# Does lateral view columns could have the same name?

Tags: sql, hive

In Hive, I have a table which has two columns: **uid** (which is a string) and **attr** (which is a map).

The map column has keys which are **contacts** and **contact** and the values of the both are strings like **18511111111 18522222222 185211111**. I want to get the following table:

uid phone

I tried the following sql:

```
select
  uid,
  phone
from
  onetalbe
lateral view explode(split(attr['contacts'], ' ')) t1 as phone
lateral view explode(split(attr['contact'], ' ')) t2 as phone
where
  length(phone)==11 and phone like '1%'
```

But I got the error:

`java.sql.SQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Column phone Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries at org.apache.hive.jdbc`

So is there a way to achive that goal? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Actually there are 2 columns regarding phone, so it is giving error.  


   select uid, t1phone, t2phone
   from onetalbe 
   lateral view explode(split(attr['contacts'], ' ')) t1 as t1phone
   lateral view explode(split(attr['contact'], ' ')) t2 as t2phone 
   where length(phone)==11 and t1phone like '1%' and t2phone  like '1%'
```

or

```
    select uid, phone
       from onetalbe 
       lateral view explode(split(attr['contacts'], ' ')) t1 as phone
       where length(phone)==11 and phone like '1%' 
UNION ALL
       select uid, phone
       from onetalbe 
       lateral view explode(split(attr['contact'], ' ')) t1 as phone
       where length(phone)==11 and phone like '1%'
```